# Permutation (and back) for a list of strings using a passphrase

Tags: java, permutation

For a given list of strings and a key (a passphrase), is there a **quick** algorithm to get a permutation using the key, and the way back using the key again?

That means

```
list = {"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"})
key = "passphrase"

permute(Key, list) -> {"def","jkl", "abc", "ghi"}
```

(or similiar, just not the original), and

```
resolve(Key, {"def","jkl", "abc", "ghi"}) -> list
```

The list is not longer than 50 entries.

A java example would be preferred.

Comment: What does "get a permutation using the key" mean?

Comment: Please include what you have attempted so far

Comment: @JoeC permutation using the key means, the permutation is determined by the key. If the key is different, the permutation is different. Think like a passphrase used for encryption.

Comment: @Andreas: found many solutions for "generate all permutations". However, I need a symmetrical way to gerneate one permutation and resolve it back using the same key, and it must be fast (not O(n^2) but less).